# Plotly Dash: How to align the tooltip to the top instead of top right

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I would like the tooltip (highlighted part of the image below) to appear on the top of the vertical bar, while it is currently on the right.

[image]

Even explored documentation of plotly bar charts and saw some tutorials, but I am not able to figure out the solution for this problem.

Data frames and bar chart code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Day": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5,8],
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Day", y="Amount",orientation="v",opacity=0.9,barmode='relative',color_discrete_sequence=["purple"],text='Day',template='none')
fig.update_traces(texttemplate = '%{text:.2s}',textposition = 'outside',width = [.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3])
```

Dash code:

```
html.Div(className="bar-chart",children=[
                    html.H1('Weekly Statistics'),
                    dcc.Dropdown( 
    ['Last Week', 'Last Month', 'Last Year'],
    'Montreal',
    clearable=False,style={'outline':'none','text-decoration':'none','width':'32vw','margin-top':'10px','margin-right':'20px','color':'#28285F','text-align':'right'}
),

dcc.Graph(
    style = {
        'display':'flex',
        'flex-direction':'column',
        'align-items':'flex-start',
        'position':'absolute',
        'width':'40vw',
        'height':'20vw',
        'margin-left':'5vw',
        'margin-top':'6vw',
        'background':'rgba(85, 190, 155, 0.1)'
    },
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    ),
                ]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to position the tooltip at the top, right (default), bottom, or left, and I have applied the [official tooltip example](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip) to your code. I have set the initial graph I create to have no hover association. I receive hover point information from the user and display it in a box. By default, the hover information is displayed after the loading display is displayed since it is a callback from the user. I am a novice in Dash and have taken most of my information from the official reference.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update
#from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Day": ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"],
    "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5,8],
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Day", y="Amount",
             orientation="v",
             opacity=0.9,
             barmode='relative',
             color_discrete_sequence=["purple"],
             text='Amount',
             hover_data=None,
             template='none')

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{text:.2s}',
                  hovertemplate=None,
                  hoverinfo='none',
                  textposition='outside',
                  width = [.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3,.3]
                 )
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[0,10]))
#fig.show()

app = Dash(__name__)
#app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    className="container",
    children=[
        dcc.Graph(
            id="graph-4",
            figure=fig,
            clear_on_unhover=True),
        dcc.Tooltip(
            id="graph-tooltip-4",
            loading_text="LOADING",
            direction="top"),
    ],
)

# This callback is executed very quickly
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function show_tooltip(hoverData) {
        if(!hoverData) {
            return [false, dash_clientside.no_update];
        }
        var pt = hoverData.points[0];
        return [true, pt.bbox];
    }
    """,
    Output("graph-tooltip-4", "show"),
    Output("graph-tooltip-4", "bbox"),
    Input("graph-4", "hoverData"),
)

# This callback is executed after 1s to simulate a long-running process
@app.callback(
    Output("graph-tooltip-4", "children"),
    Input("graph-4", "hoverData"),
)
def update_tooltip_content(hoverData):
    if hoverData is None:
        return no_update

    time.sleep(1)

    hover_data = hoverData["points"][0]

    # Display the x0 and y0 coordinate
    #bbox = hoverData["points"][0]["bbox"]
    y = hover_data['y']
    x = hover_data['x']
    # print('x:', x, 'y:',y)
    return [
        html.P(f"Day={x}, Amount={y}"),
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)#, mode='inline'
```

[image]